# What's the difference between "end up" and "be ended up"

Tags: word-usage

Is it possible to write as following sentence?

> I was ended up to have a serious injury on my left foot?

I would like to know the proper usage of "end up".

Please share the correct sentence and the knowledge behind it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Aichaku. This question would be better asked on our sister site for people learning English as a second language, [ELL.SE].

Comment: Thank you. I will ask this question to your sister site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, test your main/core structures yourself at Google Books (NOT at vanilla Google):

["I was ended up to"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20ended%20up%20having%20a%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22I%20was%20ended%20up%20to%22)

and:

["I ended up having a"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20ended%20up%20having%20a%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

You might end up :-) finding many sample sentences, and concluding that your sentence would look better this way:

***I ended up having a*** serious injury **in** my left foot.